# How can I run R interactively on a slave node, from emacs running on the head node?

Tags: r, emacs, cluster-computing, ess, rocks

Is there a way to start run R interactively on a slave node?

Although we can login to the server using qlogin, this does not allow us to launch emacs + ess, which runs on the head node.

Thanks!

as per @newuser's request, I found the following parts of the PATH variable that are only found when on the head node, but are removed from path when on the slave node

> /opt/eclipse:/opt/maven/bin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/bin

Comment: what type of cluster structure are you dealing with?

Comment: I think this is really a Rocks specific issue. I would not know a Rocks cluster if it fell on me, however. If you can get a terminal login with qlogin, can you run "emacs -nw" (non graphical Emacs)?

Comment: I suspect that emacs is not installed on the slave nodes. You may need to discuss installation with your cluster admin.

Comment: ans to JD's first question: rocks cluster on red hat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fair chance that emacs is not installed on the slave nodes. You may need to discuss installation with your cluster admin. They will need to install Emacs on each node in order for you to use it there. Keep in mind, however, that this sort of breaks the typical grid paradigm where the master node controls jobs and the slave nodes are worker bees. Generally in this paradigm one does not edit files manually on the slave nodes. I suspect that is why emacs is not installed on the slaves.

Comment: thanks for the answer. the issue is that we are slowing down the head node by running R interactively and they want us to use the slave note... so part of the challenge is to separate the computationally intensive stuff into a script or function that can be run on a node using qsub from the command line